# WCF Custom Client Inspector

Tags: wcf

An external company has given me a WSDL to consume which has a couple of odd characteristics which I don't want to impact my client code.

Firstly, each `OperationContract` requires the same username parameter sent over. Instead of setting this each time in my client code I'd like to do this globally.

I believe setting this in a `IClientMessageInspector` is my best bet, however, with this being a SOAP service I'm a little confused at how to add this into the body.

```
public class CustomInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        // Add an additional parameter to the SOAP body

        return null;
    }
}
```

Secondly, whilst the service does return mapped objects, one of the objects contains an xml document shoved in a CDATA :(

```
<a:ResponseData>

     <![CDATA[ INSERT XML DOCUMENT HERE]]>

</a:ResponseData>
```

I'm looking to extract the XML out and add it back in without the CDATA and XML declaration so I can add the appropriate properties on my response object. That way it should deserialize like normal(hope that makes sense)

```
public class CustomInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        // Get the XML from the ResponseData element and remove the CDATA. Add the XML back in (Minus the <xml> declaration)   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly, each OperationContract requires the same username parameter
>   sent over. Instead of setting this each time in my client code I'd
>   like to do this globally. I believe setting this in a
>   IClientMessageInspector is my best bet, however, with this being a
>   SOAP service I'm a little confused at how to add this into the body.

If you want to add custom message header to the message, you could refer to the following code.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("username", "", "user"));
    request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("password", "", "pass"));
    return null;
}
```

Take a look at [IClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#examples).

Here are some links may be useful to you.

[Adding custom SOAP headers from Silverlight client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925759/adding-custom-soap-headers-from-silverlight-client)

https://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f1f29779-0121-4499-a2bc-63ffe8025b21/wcf-security-soap-header

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however the values need to be set in the SOAP body. I don't own the service so I can't add it to the header.